# mongodb filtering objects between to dates using pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Below is the document structure of my collection in MongoDB.

Using pymongo I want to filter between the documents using date range on creation_date key which is inside record_status key.

Here is the structure of the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8a199cf4a98b075490bb47"),
    "Pls_Customer_Id" : "C1810151",
    "FirstName" : "SCHNEIDER ELECTRIC INDIA PVT LTD",
    "LastName" : "SCHNEIDER ELECTRIC INDIA PVT LTD",
    "Address1" : "DELHI",
    "State" : "DELHI",
    "MobileNumber" : "989898989898",
    "DeletedFlag" : false,
    "Country" : "India",
    "record_status" : {
        "created_user" : "uploadBatchProgram",
        "creation_date" : ISODate("2018-09-01T04:46:20.055Z")
    },
    "PoliciesRef" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b8a199cf4a98b075490bb45")
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "customerType" : "Regular"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter documents between `from` and `to` date ranges of `record_status.creation_date`.

Below is the code for the filter which you require.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

from_date_range = datetime(2020, 1, 1)  # Format -> (yyyy, mm, dd)
to_date_range = datetime(2020, 5, 20)  # Format -> (yyyy, mm, dd)

collection = MongoClient()["<DB-NAME>"]["<COLLECTION-NAME>"]

for cursor in collection.find({
    "record_status.creation_date": {
        "$gte": from_date_range,
        "$lt": to_date_range
    }
}):
    print(cursor)
```